# Where to find all the MaxPermSize in Eclipse-WildFly system?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Where are all the places on my system MaxPermSize might get set? I'm using Eclipse 4.4, WildFly and jdk 1.8.

I get this warning every time I stop WildFly:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I want to make it go away by replacing all the MaxPermSize by MaxMetaspaceSize. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Run -> Run Configurations in the main file menu. Find the specific instance you are trying to run.  The layout of this configuration depends on the type of project you are running, but for most, under one of the tabs you can find a section for VM arguments. For a GWT Web Application, the section is on a tab called '(x) Arguments'
2. If you are using Maven to build, check your pom.xml file.  I found two places where JVM arguments are added, once between a 'jvmArgs' tag, and again between a 'extraJvmArgs' tag.  If you do a Control + F on 'jvm' you may a place where its listed for you.