# MaxPermSize Warning in Eclipse WildFly 8 and Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, wildfly-8

i have upgraded to `WildFly 8.2.0` from `JBoss 7` and to `Java 8` from `Java 7`.

I get everytime I stop the `server` in `Eclipse` this warning:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

If I start and stop the Server from the `CMD` there is no warning like this, just in `Eclipse`. I have removed all MaxPermSize Settings from `WildFly` and can't find any setting about that in my Project. It just happens in `Eclipse`.

I have already checked this questions:

[Where to find all the MaxPermSize in Eclipse-WildFly system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932002/where-to-find-all-the-maxpermsize-in-eclipse-wildfly-system)

[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize)

[How do I make the "Java Hot Spot MaxPermSize" warning go away when using IntelliJ or Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706544/how-do-i-make-the-java-hot-spot-maxpermsize-warning-go-away-when-using-intelli)

and this page

[How do I make the "Java Hot Spot MaxPermSize" warning go away when using IntelliJ or Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706544/how-do-i-make-the-java-hot-spot-maxpermsize-warning-go-away-when-using-intelli)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to remove this argument from the "launch configuration" in your Wildfly server configuration in eclipse. It is no longer required when you are using java 8.

1) open server overview

2) click "open launch configuration"

3) edit "VM arguments" remove the " -XX:MaxPermSize=256m " argument.

4) save everything and start your wildfly via eclipse.

Message should be gone.

Comment: in Spring Tool Suite which is an extension of Eclipse when I remove the MaxPermSize argument and save it seems to just return as soon as I start the TCserver again.

Comment: @JesseBoyd try restarting STS after applying your changes.

Comment: I followed your step by step and the message is no longer displayed! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Java8 the Perm partition of memory has changed to Metaspace. In this way, the parameters has changed from "-XX:PermSize" and "-XX:MaxPermSize" to "-XX:MetaspaceSize" and "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize".

Instead of removing the parameter, change it for bla

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when WildFly lunch from e-clips in Java 11.
I started server from standalone.bat  at startup you get VM arguments which are suitable for Java version.
Copy the arguments and

1. open server overview
2. click "open launch configuration"
3. edit "VM arguments" past arguments value[image]
4. save everything and start your wildfly via eclipse.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.